# How do I separate the attributes of a class in a Django admin form in sections?

Tags: django

Django admin site shows the attributes of a class in a form so you can add a new object, I want to know if there is an easy way to separate the attributes in sections to make the form more organized, like having a "Physical features" section title over fields about physical features, similar to how inline attibutes work having the name of the inline class as a section name.

Default form:
[image: Admin for as it is.]

Sketch showing how I imagine a section:
[image]

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you make a sketch (for example edit a screenshot) or something similar?

Comment: Done, @WillemVanOnsem, uploaded sketch, thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe fieldsets is what you are after, see the Django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

You will need to put this code within your `admin.py` file and the registration of your model.